# AccountManagerFuture.getResult taking too long to get token in android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I am implementing android AccountManager, everything is working fine, except mAccountManager.getAuthToken() function, it is taking too long to get token. Here is the code that i am using to get token.

```
final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(account, AccountTags.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY_ACCESS, null, activity, null, null);
   Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Bundle bnd = future.getResult();
                final String authtoken =     bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                Log.d("TangoAccounts", "GetToken Bundle is " + bnd);
                SingeltonToken.getInstance().setToken(authtoken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Problem is not with server connection as it is on local network and all other requests to server are taking less than a second to complete even login request of account manager take less than a second but when i call getAuthToken after after first login it takes around 2 minutes to complete. I tried by invalidating authToken before calling  getAuthToken but it still takes too much time. I tried debugging and found out that code stuck at this line

```
Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
```